# How do I define a parser function for variables?

Tags: haskell

I need help creating a parser for ternary expressions. I'm given this grammar for ternary expressions.

```
tExp :: tOpd ( '<=>' tExp | '==>' tExp| e )
tOpd :: tTerm ( '|||' tOpd | e )
tTerm :: tFact ( '&&&' tTerm | e)
tFact :: '~' tPrim | tPrim
primary :: tVar | tLit | '('tExp')'
tVar :: lowercase (Alphanumeric)*
tLit :: T | F | M
```

I also have defined the data type Ternary and expression tree here.

```
data Ternary = T | F | M
    deriving (Eq,  Show, Ord) 

   data TExpTree = L Ternary              -- Ternary literal (i.e. T, F or M)
                  | V String               -- Variable 
                  | N TExpTree             -- Prefix not
                  | A TExpTree TExpTree    -- And node
                  | O TExpTree TExpTree    -- Or node
                  | E TExpTree TExpTree    -- Equivalence node
                  | I TExpTree TExpTree    -- Implication node
        deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I know that first I need to create functions for each rule.

```
tExp:: Parser TExpTree
tExp = do o <- tOpd
          (do symbol "<=>"
              e <- tExp
              return (e<=>o)
           +++ do synbol "==>"
              e <- tExp
              return (e==>o)
           +++ return o)

tOpd :: Parser TExpTree
tOpd = do t <- tTerm
          (do symbol "|||"
              e <- tOpd
              return (t|||e)
           +++ return t)

tTerm :: Parser TExpTree
tTerm = do f <- tFact
          (do symbol "&&&"
              e <- tTerm
              return (f+e)
           +++ return f)

tFact:: Parser TExpTree 
tFact = do m <- tPrim
           return m
        +++
           (do symbol "~"
              m <- tExp
              return (~m))
```

So far, I have these, but I don't know how to go about creating them for primary, tLit, and tVar.

Can someone help me figure out just tLit, so I can try doing the rest myself? I'm not sure how to go about this.

I have this test function for tLit to confirm that it works as well.

```
testtLit :: Bool
testtLit = lt == (L T) && lf == (L F) && lm == (L M)  
       where Just (lt, _) = parse tLit " T " 
             Just (lf, _) = parse tLit " F "
             Just (lm, _) = parse tLit " M "
```

Comment: This doesn't look correct at all (it doesn't parse, for starters). You have defined data TExpTree but aren't using it, are you sure you want your parsers to be of type `Parser Ternary` rather than say `Parser TExpTree`?

Comment: I think you're right about the TExpTree.  What do you mean by it doesn't parse?  I thought this is how you set it up.

Comment: I get parse errors from the compiler.

Comment: What parser library are you using?

Comment: im using this file that was given to me. https://pastebin.com/0ZFGKLk4
and here is the rest of my code with things defined and the other test functions. https://pastebin.com/6spicVmK

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing a parser and an evaluator in a single function. Because of that, you never use `TExpTree`. If you want to build a parser, change the type of your parser functions to `Parser TExpTree`. Then, let `tExp` return `(I e o)` instead of `(e==>o)`, and so on.

The implementation of the `tLit` function depends on the tools your parser offers. It could look like this (untested):

```
tLit :: Parser TExpTree
tLit = (symbol "T" >> return (L T))
   <|> (symbol "F" >> return (L F))
   <|> (symbol "M" >> return (L M))
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error.  The error might be either ((:)) or ((|)), I cant tell because it looks like a colon but its probably ((|))
The error says variable not in scope: ((:))  :: Parser TExpTree -> Parser TExpTree -> t0 Perhaps you meant one of these: () (=) Variable not in scope: ((:)) :: t0-> Parser TExpTree -> TExpTree Perhaps you meant one of these: (*) (=) What does this mean?

Comment: There is no `:` or `|` in the code. Perhaps you meant `<|>`? It is imported from `Control.Applicative`. `<|>` expresses an alternative. So `a <|> b` means: Try `a` first, and if it fails, try `b`.